# Beautiful Soup nth-of-type selector selects only one element

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using the following CSS selector to select all `td` tags which are `first-of-type` : `.wikitable tr td:nth-of-type(1)`. The problem is that it only selects one element. The same selector in CSS stylesheet selects all the first-of-type `td` on the page. Why is that? Does the Beautiful Soup selector work differently?

[Link to the webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_1940). I want the following output:

> Aaj Ka Hindustan, Aaj Ki Duniya, Aandhi ....

Basically, I want the name of all the movies.

Comment: post the html or url

Comment: @宏杰李 I have added the link. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for tr in soup.select('.wikitable tr'):
    if len(tr('td')) == 5:
        print(tr.td.text)
```

out:

```
Aaj Ka Hindustan
Aaj Ki Duniya
Aandhi
Abla Ki Shakti
Achhut
Aflatoon Aurat
Alakh Niranjan a.k.a. Gorakhnath
Alibaba
Anarbala
```

Comment: Thanks 宏杰李. But it prints all the tags instead of just the first one.

Comment: @Neena Vivek post the output you want in the question.

Comment: I have added the output in question details. :)

Comment: @Neena Vivek Done

Comment: How does this work? You seem to be checking if there are five columns. I guess that's because there are five columns in the table. But how does that help in just printing the text from first column?

Comment: @Neena Vivek  the first `td` is 1990, not a title. I want to jump it and make the code more stable.